# PHP not redirecting after submision

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $additionalIDs = array("williamhew","anthon9","geroyi");
        $rA = array_rand($additionalIDs,1);
        $merchantNick   = ".membership.com";
        $gen_link = $additionalIDs[$rA].$merchantNick;
        header("Location: http://$gen_link");
    }
?>

<input type ="submit" name="submit"  ></input>
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't redirect after I clicked submit. Is there anything wrong in this code??
I need assist from you guys :(.

Edit:

Using this also can't redirect,

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        ob_start();
        header("Location: http://www.facebook.com");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: tried header("Location: http://".$gen_link); ?

Comment: @MarcoMura, i tried it already even with http://www.facebook.com also doesn't work.

Comment: Your submit element is not in a form tag.

Comment: Do you use the `ob_start` call to get rid of any warnings/errors? Do you get any warnings/errors?

Comment: do you send headers before? (like html) header need to be the only line you print for browser o_o try eventually to put the header (static) before isset and before error_reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the INPUT element in a `<form>` tag with a param method="post", like this:

```
<form method="post">
      <input type ="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And by the way, INPUT is a self closing tag, so instead of `<input type ="submit" name="submit"  ></input>`  you can write it like this: `<input type ="submit" name="submit" />`

Answer (score 0):

You're either outputting something before the header, in which case it will not redirect.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Or the link itself is invalid. Which is not out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
<form method="post">
    <input type ="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Use window.location instead of header location

```
<?php
echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";
} ?>
```

Comment: Using a javascript workaround for php business is usually not good practice.